# Models in which the vacuum energy gravitates on small scales but not on large scales

Tags: vacuum, cosmological-constant

Are there models in which the vacuum energy gravitates on small scales but the effect is diluted on large scales?

Comment: Given that the vacuum in a homogeneous and isotropic universe has the same stress-energy everywhere, how could that happen?

Comment: Not necessarily, see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00543

Comment: Thanks for that very interesting reference.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0703027

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer is a very incomplete review. Please look at the papers and their references and papers that cite them for a more complete picture.)

This basic idea is called "degravitation". The idea is that gravity is modified on large scales in such a way that it does not "see" the full effect of the cosmological constant.

At a words level, it is a very good idea. The vacuum energy from quantum field theory can take a natural value, but it does not contribute much to the acceleration of the Universe due to a large scale modification of gravity.

However, specific models that have tried to implement this idea have run into problems.

The famous DGP model [2] proposes we live on a brane in an infinite extra dimension. Gravity on our brane becomes modified at large distances, in a way that (it was hoped) would screen the cosmological constant. However, solutions in DGP that screen the cosmological constant have a ghost instability [3].

Cascading gravity (see, eg, [4, 5, 6]) attempted to resolve the ghost issue by having a set of nested branes in higher dimensions. The ghost was resolved. However, another issue was that in order to have degravitation, the brane tension needed to be large. This created a contradiction where the brane would create a "deficit angle" larger than $2\pi$, which is impossible. There was a potential solution suggested in [5] by using a different mechanism (not degravitation), but proving this solution worked required controlling a lot of non-linear effects and was difficult to make progress.

Another idea for implementing degravitation was massive gravity (some refs include [7, 8, 9]), which gives the graviton a small mass. You would then expect this mass would "cut off" gravity at scales larger than the Compton wavelength. Massive gravity has a long history, and there are many twists in the story. However, to keep things short, the degravitation solution has an unscreened fifth force, which makes it phenomenologically unviable [10]. It's possible that there are cosmological solutions that are non-homogeneous/non-isotropic on very large scales that get around the issues in [10], but somewhat like with cascading gravity, this pushes the theory into the realm where it's hard to make progress (although for different reasons).

---

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0703027

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0005016

[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512097

[4] https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2072

[5] https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2821

[6] https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0269

[7] https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1232

[8] https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3735

[9] https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4173

[10] https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5231